# kotlin quick return for throwable coroutine chain

Tags: kotlin

There are more than one strategies to try, each strategy is a suspend function. We run them one by one in serial and return if one success. The following is an abstract implemention for my use case. but i believe it's too redundant. Is there a better implemention?

```kotlin
       suspend fun f1() =
            suspendCoroutine { cont ->
                if (Random.nextBoolean()) {
                    cont.resume(Unit)
                } else {
                    cont.resumeWithException(Exception())
                }
            }

        suspend fun f2() =
            suspendCoroutine { cont ->
                if (Random.nextBoolean()) {
                    cont.resume(Unit)
                } else {
                    cont.resumeWithException(Exception())
                }
            }

        runBlocking {
            runCatching {
                f1()
            }.onSuccess {
                return@runBlocking
            }

            runCatching {
                f2()
            }.onSuccess {
                return@runBlocking
            }

            // more
        }
```

Comment: I can't test this right now, but why not to return directly: `return@runBlocking f1()`, without `onSuccess`?

Comment: because if f1() fail, we need to try f2()

Comment: Yes, and my suggested solution does exactly this, doesn't it? See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As an option I would propose something like this:

```
fun firstSuccess() {
    runBlocking {
        listOf(::f1, ::f2).forEach { func ->
            try {
                func()
                return@runBlocking
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("Exception is thrown")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful: `return@forEach` won't break from the loop, it will just continue to the next iteration. If you want to break on success, you would need `return@runBlocking`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a huge fan of replacing `try ... catch` with `runCatching()`, but if you already do this, then please be aware you don't need these `onSuccess {}` blocks. You can return directly:

```kotlin
runBlocking {
    runCatching {
        return@runBlocking f1()
    }
    runCatching {
        return@runBlocking f2()
    }
}
```

However, if you already talk about the "strategy" and "chain", that feels like you really expect to have an arbitrary list of operations in the chain. If you expect the list may change in the future or it may contain a bigger number of operations, then I think it makes more sense to store them in a list and executing in the loop - as @Mike suggested in the answer.

Also, you need to remember about the case when even the last operation failed. Right now it is indistinguishable from the "failed but then succeeded" case.

Comment: this code is amazing! and if using `try ... catch` instead of `runCatching`, this code will be longer, right?

Comment: @bilabila Yes, I know, `runCatching` is definitely more concise and actually in this specific case it looks pretty neat. I don't say it is bad. I just think it was never designed to be used to ignore errors.